# Why m3u8 file does not play well when i manual change m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8, hls.js

I use `ffmpeg` to change mp4 to .ts

```
ffmpeg -y -i [fileName].mp4 -vcodec copy  -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb [outPutFileName].ts
```

And get the following `index.m3u8` file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:22
#EXTINF:21.804344,
out-0000.ts
#EXTINF:10.847822,
out-0001.ts
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

And then i use `hls.js` play this file

It works fine

But now i want to change this `index.m3u8` file to this (copy this  out02.ts twice, to repeat out02.ts)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:22
#EXTINF:21.804344,
out-0000.ts
#EXTINF:10.847822,
out-0001.ts
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

The result is this video `play time` change as expected

but out02 does not repeat, when it play to end of first out02.ts, screen stuck at the begin of out00

Why it does not work fine when i edit this file by myself ?
or i shoule use `ffmpeg` update this `index.m3u8` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was asked and answered here: [hls manually add second .ts file to playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132833/hls-manually-add-second-ts-file-to-playlist) and here: [How to include same segment into m3u8 playlist multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652711/how-to-include-same-segment-into-m3u8-playlist-multiple-times)

From there, you just need the piece of information that you need to mark each and every discontinuity in the m3u8 file. You do it by adding the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY flag.

For example, your m3u8 file should look like the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:22
#EXTINF:21.804344,
out-0000.ts
#EXTINF:10.847822,
out-0001.ts
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:12.239122,
out-0002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

This is because playing over and again the out-0002.ts resets the video presentation timestamps over and again, causing a discontinuity, as the ending of the out-0002.ts file has timestamp values 12.239122 seconds after the timestamps of the beginning of the same file.

Further information here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216

> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag indicates a discontinuity between the
> Media Segment that follows it and the one that preceded it.
> [...]
> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag MUST be present if there is a change in
> any of the following characteristics:
> file format;
> number, type, and identifiers of tracks;
> timestamp sequence.
> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag SHOULD be present if there is a change in
> any of the following characteristics:
> encoding parameters;
> encoding sequence.